# AWS specific parameters and EC2 SecurityGroupIds List String Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a rather annoying issue which I am unable to resolve and will do my best to explain.

The following cut down example works in which I am able to reference a parameter and assign the security groups to my instance via the SecurityGroupIds property:

```js
"Parameters" : {
      "pDefaultSg" : {
        "Description" : "AWS2 VPC default security groups",
        "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>",
        "Default" : "sg-245xxxxx,sg-275xxxxx,sg-235xxxxx" 
      }
    }

    "Resources" : {
      "ec2Instance" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties" : {
        "SecurityGroupIds" : { "Ref" : "pDefaultSg" } 
      }
}
```

The issue begins when I also want to add a second value to the SecurityGroupIds property referencing a security group resource instantiated within the same template:

```js
"Resources" : {
    "ec2Instance" : { ...
        "SecurityGroupIds" : [ { "Ref" : "pDefaultSg" }, { "Fn::GetAtt" : "sgDb", "GroupId" } ],
    ....  

    "sgDb" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties" : { ...
```

I am then unable to avoid the following error causing the Cloudformation stack to rollback:

Value of property SecurityGroupIds must be of type List of String

I would really appreciate any pointers.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when `pDefaultSg` is accessed via the `Ref` intrinsic function it returns a list, therefore your `SecurityGroupIds` Property looks like

```json
[["sg-245xxxxx","sg-275xxxxx","sg-235xxxxx"],"sg-1234DB"]
```

The solution is to change your `SecurityGroupIds` Property to `Fn::Join` the `pDefaultSg` List to a comma separated string followed by the `sgDb`:

```json
"SecurityGroupIds": [ 
  {"Fn::Join": 
    [",", 
      {"Ref": "pDefaultSg"}
    ]
  }, 
  { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["sgDb", "GroupId"] } 
]
```

Comment: Many thanks and very much along the lines of what I was trying to achieve, though now I get "The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet".   There is no easy way to debug cloudformation which makes it more fun :)  Thanks again

Comment: Thanks I think this Answers your original question ;) 

one way to help testing templates is to run

`aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://${file}`

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with your above error, maybe you could post it as a separate question with more information ? 

Thanks

Comment: It certainly does and I appreciate your help, if I am unable to solve subsequent issue I will submit another question.  Just to add, validate-template only validates the JSON and such issues are only presented upon instantiation.